# Python, regex negative lookbehind behavior

Tags: python, regex

I have a regular experssion that should find up to 10 words in a line. THat is, it should include the word just preceding the line feed but not the words after the line feed. I am using a negative lookbehind with "\n".

```
a = re.compile(r"((\w)+[\s /]){0,10}(?<!\n)")
r = a.search("THe car is parked in the garage\nBut the sun is shining hot.")
```

When I execute this regex and call the method r.group(), I am getting back the whole sentence but the last word that contains a period. I was expecting only the complete string preceding the new line. That is, "THe car is parked in the garage\n".
What is the mistake that I am making here with the negative look behind...?

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some more examples? The discussion below has confused me as to exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would use negative lookahead. You are saying that you want a maximum of 10 words before a linefeed. The regex below should work. It uses a positive lookahead to ensure that there **is** a linefeed after the words. Also when searching for words use `b\w+\b` instead of what you were using.

```
/(\b\w+\b)*(?=.*\\n)/
```

Python :

```
result = re.findall(r"(\b\w+\b)*(?=.*\\n)", subject)
```

**Explanation :**

```
# (\b\w+\b)*(?=.*\\n)
# 
# Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(\b\w+\b)*»
#    Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
#    Note: You repeated the capturing group itself.  The group will capture only the last iteration.  Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations. «*»
#    Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
#    Match a single character that is a “word character” (letters, digits, etc.) «\w+»
#       Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «+»
#    Assert position at a word boundary «\b»
# Assert that the regex below can be matched, starting at this position (positive lookahead) «(?=.*\\n)»
#    Match any single character that is not a line break character «.*»
#       Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «*»
#    Match the character “\” literally «\\»
#    Match the character “n” literally «n»
```

You may also wish to consider the fact that there could be no \n at your string.

Comment: Actually I would like to find up to ten words from the beginning of the line. The problem is that in some cases I may have fewer words in the line and there is a newline (\n) directly after the last word (for example ...hot\n). In this case I want also to include the last word.

Comment: @user963386 I am confused. Could you please post samples inputs and outputs so that you can make your problem clearer?

Comment: Example 1: "I am driving\nTomorrow the sun is hot\nlI will fish" In this case I would like to find "Tomorrow the sun is hot"

Comment: @user963386 Please put the examples in your question.

Comment: Example 1: "I am driving\nTomorrow the sun is hot\nlI will fish" In this case I would like to find "Tomorrow the sun is hot" Example2: "the text is very long very long very long yes yes yes ". In this case I would like to find the first ten words "the text is "the text is very long very long very long yes" (first 10 words).

Comment: @user963386 I don't see the correlation between your two examples. In 1st you want the words in between \n whereas in the seconds, there are no \n involved at all. What is the connection between the two examples?

Answer (score 0):

For this task there is the anchor `$` to find the the end of the string and together with the modifier `re.MULTILINE`/`re.M` it will find the end of the line. So you would end up with something like this

```
(\b\w+\b[.\s /]{0,2}){0,10}$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v571)

The `\b` is a word boundary. I included `[.\s /]{0,2}` to match a dot followed by a whitespace in my example. If you don't want the dots you need to make this part at least optional like this `[\s /]?` otherwise it will be missing at the last word and then the `\s` is matching the `\n`.

**Update/Idea 2**

OK, maybe I misunderstood your question with my first solution.

If you just want to not match a newline and continue in the second row, then just don't allow it. The problem is that the newline is matched by the `\s` in your character class. The `\s` is a class for whitespace and this includes also the newline characters `\r` and `\n`

You already have a space in the class then just replace the `\s` with `\t` in case you want to allow tab and then you should be fine without lookbehind. And of course, make the character class optional otherwise the last word will also not be matched.

```
((\w)+[\t /]?){0,10}
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2v58t)

Comment: Isn't this always going to return the *last* ten words in the input?

Comment: @N3dst4 together with the multiline modifier it will return the last 10 words before a line break.

Comment: Thanks Stema. However I do not understand why the look behind (negative) is not working to exclude the "new line". The \s will include the newline but the negative look behind for newline should "exclude"the newline.

Comment: @user963386 because your lookbehind is in the wrong position. It looks back from its position, its the last part in your regex so it will match everything you allow and then checks if the last matched character is a `\n`, see @N3dst4 answer he has the lookbehind in the correct place.

Comment: May be I misunderstood the "negative look behind". I thought that the "negative look behind" placed at the end of the pattern was going to look at the "match" and reject it if the last character in the match is a \n. Do you mean that if I have matched the \n in my match,the \n is consumed and the "negative look behind will not see it?

Comment: @user963386 Yes this will happen, but I think this is not what you want, my understanding is that you want to check before each word if the character before this word is `\n`.

Answer (score 0):

If I read you right, you want to read up to 10 words, or the first newline, whichever comes first:

```
((?:(?<!\n)\w+\b[\s.]*){0,10})
```

This uses a negative lookbehind, but just *before* the word match, so it blocks getting any word *after* a newline.

This will need some tuning for imperfect input, but it's a start.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't be using a lookbehind at all.  If you want to match up to ten words not including a newline, try this:

```
\S+(?:[ \t]+\S+){0,9}
```

A word is defined here as one or more non-whitespace characters, which includes periods, apostrophes, and other sentence punctuation as well as letters.  If you know the text you're matching is regular prose, there's no point limiting yourself to `\w+`, which isn't really meant to match natural-language words anyway.

After the first word, it repeatedly matches one or more horizontal whitespace characters (space or TAB) followed by another word, for a maximum of ten words.  If it encounters a newline before the tenth word, it simply stops matching at that point.  There's no need to mention newlines in the regex at all.